# Sunspot returns duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

For some reason, my Sunspot is returning duplicate values. What could be the cause?

Here is my search block:

```
@search = Item do |query|
  query.with :menu_ids, @menu.id
  query.with :public, true

  case @type
  when "popularity"
    query.order_by :popularity, :desc
  when "store"
    query.with :store_id, @stores.map(&:id)
  when "special"
    query.with :special, true
  end

  query.order_by :published_at, :desc

  if @tag
    query.fulltext @tag
  end

  query.with :price, @filters[:low]..@filters[:high] if @filters[:low] && @filters[:high]
  query.with :state, 'published'
end

@items = @search.results
```

I get 30 items, but 6 of them are duplicates.

Comment: Solr would return duplicate values only if you index duplicate values. Are the ids duplicate ? what are you indexing and what duplicates are being returned ?

Comment: In my Rails project, I index each of my Item model/record. Each item is basically a row in the database. They are unique by primary key. But Sunspot (solr wrapper) is returning the same item (with the same primary key) twice.

Comment: Did you mark in solr the id as unique field ? else the documents will be indexed as multiple documents causing duplicates to be returned.

Comment: Sunspot probably already handles that. Since this didn't happen before.

Comment: do the duplicates as the same id ? does the schema.xml mention the id as the unique key ?

Comment: Do you solved your issue? Same here... :/